# Nginx fails to serve files from 9p

Tags: nginx, 9p

I have a VM with a 9p share and nginx. It worked fine until I updated my VM to Debian 10. Since then, it fails to serve files from my 9p share. Nginx returns an empty response and
`2020/09/11 09:57:49 [alert] 864#864: *449 pread() read only 4096 of 32768 from "/9p/test.png" while sending response to client`
Files under 4096 work. Anything over 4096 will fail. It always says 'read only 4096 of xxxx'. File cache isn't enabled. What could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason could be that 9p driver in guest kernel is incompatible with the 9p driver on host.

Try using same kernel on both guest and host.